Visual Studio Designer changes code so much that UI no longer works
I'm trying to add to a project of a colleague which is an UI for a monitoring program. Adding new UI elements to the project or changing existing ones results in the designer recompiling the designer.cs in such a way that the UI is no longer as it should be.
The only changes made to the solution are in the designer.cs and the view.resx file. My colleague making the same change of moving the textbox results in no issue at all. I've verified that I'm using the same SDK, platforms and visual studio version.
I've tried all I can think of like fresh installs, comparing settings etc. but can't seem to figure out the cause.
The changes don't have to be big either, as shown by moving a textbox 2 pixels to the left:
Example view of the UI as it should be without any UI changes made by me:
UI working as intended
If I change the "stream to file" textbox 2 pixels to the left in the designer:
UI with minimal changes made to 1 element

Have you used the designer with a different desktop zoom then the other developer? That is mostly not a good idea. At best always use 100% zoom. If you do a diff of the before and after designer.cs, at best via the compare tool of your versioning system, and you see that dpi settings changed that might be the source of your problem.

this sounds like it could be the issue, I'll try it out next time and let you know if that solves it.

It looks like this solved the issue. I feel stupid for missing this, but as a first-time user, I had no clue that the software's automatic scaling had an effect on the final outcome.. Thanks a lot!

Scaling shouldn't have that effect but you are sitting on pretty old technique with winforms from times when scaling wasn't a thought. Any scaling possible now is more of a retrofit then an actual feature of winforms.
